# Replace a string in MySQL

Tags: mysql, wordpress, woocommerce

I need a little help with replacing a string in my MySQL database.

I am running Woocommerce on top of a MySQL database.

I need to change a company name from 'oldname' to 'Old Name'. The thing is that my domain name is www.oldname.com

I'm not sure how to do this change, without also changing all the settings for Woocommerce / Wordpress.

Comment: First of all it would be better if you give some table info from where you want to change this. Also The name of your company is in a url format and you want to change it to a plain name? Because if this is the case you will probably mess up with some functionality that is using that URL.

Comment: The URL that i want to change is, lets say.. www.companystore.com. And i want to change Companystore to Company Store. I afraid to do that, because i think that www.companystore.com will become www.Company Store.com in the settings in the database. So, if it was possible to do some kind of filter so it will not change anything if something comes before of after. Hope this makes sense.

Comment: I see. It probably be better if you estudy the plugin (woocomerce) that you are using because, it is for sure, there is somewhere to put a name to identify your url. Like on the woocomerce maybe you are looking to the url field of the database, you should look for the name related ot it.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

- Export database
- open export-file
- String replace all oldname's to New Name's
- Import database

You could do this in one go, but I guess you want some human validation, so I recommend doing it by hand (with a find+replace).

You can do this table by table (if your structure allows this), or the whole thing at once.